NFS permission for other - operation not permitted
I have the following problem with NFS:

On the server:
$ cat /etc/exports
/opt/1865/conf/ 10.10.14.196(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)

$ id
uid=999(usr1) gid=1003(grp1) groups=1003(grp1)


On the client:
$ cat /etc/fstab | grep nfs
10.10.14.195:/opt/1865/conf/  /mnt/conf/  nfs4 defaults 0 0

$ id
uid=999(usr1) gid=1003(grp1) groups=1003(grp1)


On the client I can create file and have access to it:
$ touch t.fl

$ ls -n t.fl
-rw-r--r-- 1 999 1003 0 may 17 23:11 t.fl

$ cat t.fl
$


But if I change file permissions to 440, then I lose access to the file:
$ chmod 440 t.fl

$ ls -n t.fl
-r--r----- 1 999 1003 0 may 17 23:11 t.fl

$ cat t.fl
cat: t.fl: Operation not permitted


On server user, usr1 has access to /opt/1865/conf/t.fl:
$ cat /opt/1865/conf/t.fl
$



Why does changing the rights of others affect access to a file owned by a user?

You're using NFSv4, and your server and client are using different NFS domain settings, and/or you are using a distribution that has NFSv4 idmapping enabled by default when using the default sec=sys NFSv4 security mode, or you are accidentally mounting the NFS share in sec=none mode instead of sec=sys. Some distributions may require you to explicitly specify sec=sys as a mount option when mounting NFSv4 shares.
As a result, if you create a world-writeable directory in the NFS share on the server, and then use the NFS client to create a file in it as user usr1, you may find that the file will be owned by a [nfs]nobody user instead of user usr1 as expected. That would prove the NFSv4 server treats the user usr1@client as a separate entity from usr1@server, and that when you are reading the server-created file, it is the world-read permission that actually allows you to do so.
To verify the state of the sec= mount option, run grep /mnt/conf /proc/mounts. That should show you the actual NFS mount options negotiated for this NFS mount. If it shows sec=none, change the client-side /etc/fstab entry to
10.10.14.195:/opt/1865/conf/  /mnt/conf/  nfs4 defaults,sec=sys 0 0

Then unmount & remount the NFS share.
The kernel default for the idmapping setting was changed back in year 2012, to make it easier to make NFSv4 work like older versions of NFS, as the change to the NFSv4 specification in RFC3530bis made it a legitimate configuration. Some distributions may have kept the older default to match their original NFSv4 behavior.
Very old NFSv4 implementations (e.g. RHEL5 and older) might not support UID-number-based access control on NFSv4 at all.
You can disable the mapping in either server or client-side, in a number of ways. Depending on the client and server versions, you might have do this at both sides.
Server-side:

you could add a nfsd module option:
echo "options nfsd nfs4_disable_idmapping=Y" >> /etc/modprobe.d/nfs.conf


You can make this module option take effect without rebooting with:
echo Y > /sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping


or if your rpc.idmapd daemon supports a -S option, add it to whatever mechanism is used to start rpc.idmapd on the NFS server.

Client-side:

you could add a nfs module option:
echo "options nfs nfs4_disable_idmapping=Y" >> /etc/modprobe.d/nfs.conf


You can make this module option take effect without rebooting with:
echo Y > /sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping


or if your distribution uses rpc.idmapd instead of the newer nfsidmap upcall program and the rpc.idmapd supports the -C option, add it to whatever mechanism is used to start rpc.idmapd on the client and restart rpc.idmapd.

To make the change effective on the actual NFS mount, you'll need to run nfsidmap -c on the client (if available) to clear stale maps from the kernel, and then unmount & remount the NFS mount. You might choose to reboot the client instead.
For others who might have a similar problem with a NetApp NAS, make sure the NetApp configuration parameter nfs.v4.id.allow_numerics is enabled.

If you can get the ID mapping successfully disabled, then NFSv4 should work using UID/GID numbers, similar to NFSv3 and older. But just in case, you might have to make sure the NFS domain is set to the same value in both the NFS server and the client.
To check the NFS domain of a Linux system, use nfsidmap -d as root. To set it, add Domain = <desired value> in the [General] section of /etc/idmapd.conf.
For Solaris, see NFSMAPID_DOMAIN in /etc/default/nfs.
For a NetApp NAS, see the configuration parameter nfs.v4.id.domain.

Thank you for such a detailed answer. sec=sys used in my systems by default. But already in both side cat /sys/module/nfsd/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping Y I  have reduced NFSMAPID_DOMAIN to one value. I remounted the NFS, but it didn't help.

Note that the server-side parameters are in /sys/module/ nfsd /parameters/ while the corresponding client-side parameters are in /sys/module/ nfs /parameters/.
